# extension for UIViewController is not Working change UIStatusBarStyle In Swift

Tags: swift, statusbar, reusability

I am Try to Create **extension** for **UIViewController** but Its not working . i am changing status bar color for using extension but i cant get success. But without extension is working. I am new in Extension Please help me. 
My Aim is **I DONT WANT TO CREATE FUNCTION ON EVERY VIEW CONTROLLER , REDUSE REUSABILITY**
**Create Extension Is Not Working**

```
extension UIViewController {

     func preferredStatusBarStyle_change() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }
}
//!!!!!!!!!view1
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //preferredStatusBarStyle();
        self.preferredStatusBarStyle_change();
    }
//!!!!!!!!!view2
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //preferredStatusBarStyle();
        self.preferredStatusBarStyle_change();
    }
```

**Without Extension IS Working**

```
View1
override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                preferredStatusBarStyle();
            }
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
            return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
        } 
View2

     override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                preferredStatusBarStyle();
            }

         override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
                return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
            }
```

Help me Try to understanding Reusability and extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not working because:

Viewcontroller will call `preferredStatusBarStyle()` for define about `statusbar`. Actually you remove `preferredStatusBarStyle();` in `viewDidload`, your controller still work.

So in your case you can resolve like this:

You create a subclass of `UIViewController` maybe name it is: `BaseViewController` and it this class you put:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
     return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

And now all your `ViewController` you inherited from  `BaseViewController` status bar will always `.LightContent` you don't need put this code above every where.

Demo: [Demo](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoSubClassForStatusBar)

Comment: Please give me any link Its Help me for how to create subclass and and how to inherit in my main view Controler Please

Comment: @user3899589 It is very simple. I will give you a Demo.

Comment: @user3899589  check my demo

Comment: I have found This File "addContraint.m" I think Example in This File name  Where is Link .May be you are Talking about This Link "https://gist.github.com/vienvu89" ?

Comment: @user3899589 what about this file? It is my gist file for some snip set I create for my convenient.

Comment: In This Demo Not use subclass(BaseViewController) How to use baseclass in viewcontroller 1 and viewController 2 . Please help me

Comment: class ViewController: BaseViewController

class ViewController2: BaseViewController

they have already used.